# Submit Contact form asynchronous and show Result in a Modal like fancy box using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, asynchronous

I have a simple Contact form and  i have to submit it asynchronous and then i have to display result in a Modal like window more like Fancybox.

```
<form name='contactForm'>
    <input type="text"  name="Fname" />
     <input type="text"  name="Lname" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

I dont have experience of working in PHP still i can manage to submit form data asynchronous and display data in a div area but i am not sure how i can display the RESULT in a fancybox or something similar which will greyout the background and show the success message.

I also need to Validate form before i submit it.

Comment: "in a fancybox manner" is very subjective.

Comment: PHP is server-side. What you are trying to do looks like client-side processing and so HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: @Francisc I want to save data in the database and then display a confirmation message in an overlay div tag something similar to fancybox

Comment: Yeah, you use HTML, CSS and JS for that. You send the AJAX request using JS to the PHP file which saves to DB and returns a result which is read in the AJAX callback which then shows an absolutely positioned `<div>` (or whatever) showing the message.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to write your application, but I'd tell you how I'd approach it:

1. Serialize the data and send it via an AJAX Request (using jQuery).
2. On success, use the fancybox plugin to display "Thank you for contacting us".

You can get jQuery [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery).

Fancybox and Docs are [here](http://fancybox.net/).

[Using AJAX and jQuery.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

[jQuery validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Since you didn't really provide any detail on a specific question, this is the best I can really do. If you take the time to familiarize yourself with the Docs on each of these links, I am sure you will be able to pull this off very easily.  From what you already have, the only thing left would be to just learn the Fancybox plugin, which can be invoked with 1 line of code.